# Is there a better way to cycle through a series of classes on click than this javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have set myself a little project to make use of pure javascript rather than simply resorting to jquery. In this attempt my aim is to click on an element and when I do it changes colour or whatever, when I click again another it changes to another colour, and so on until I reach the end of my choices at which point we start again. To do this I am adding and removing classes.

```
// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
// addClass
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
// removeClass
function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
     }
}

document.getElementById('plug1').onclick = function() {
    if (hasClass(document.getElementById('plug1'), 'old')) {
        addClass(this, 'red');
        removeClass(this, 'old');
    }
    else if (hasClass(document.getElementById('plug1'), 'red')) {
        addClass(this, 'green');
        removeClass(this, 'red');
    }
    else if (hasClass(document.getElementById('plug1'), 'green')) {
        addClass(this, 'blue');
        removeClass(this, 'green');
    }
    else if (hasClass(document.getElementById('plug1'), 'blue')) {
        addClass(this, 'red');
        removeClass(this, 'blue');
    }
}
```

Having successfully cobbled together the code above from a variety of google searches, I wondered is there is a more efficient way of doing this as it seems a little long winded?

[A jsFiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbmxfm4k/) for those who are interested.

Also as a second part to my question, I originally tried to use .getElementsByClassName as the intention would be to have the same functionality on several elements however when I replaced getElementById with getElementsByClassName it failed. So how might I apply the same to a class rather than an Id?

Comment: Your question is too open-ended for Stack Overflow, so i'm going to vote to close it as primarily opinion based. It is, I believe, a good candidate for [codereview.se].

Comment: or use modern browser's [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: It fails because getElementsByClassName returns an HTML Collection and you would need to loop over the collection...

Comment: @zzzzBov I think you are right for the first part of my question. Code Review would be ideal for that in isolation, but as I'm also looking at trying to achieve the same process with classes as I have here with Ids I think its more than just a rationalisation of the code. That said, if I had known about code Review previously I may have split it into two parts, so thank you for introducing me to Code Review, I reckon it could prove useful in the future, so plus one just for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is that you want.
Using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) it is easier ;)

```js
// Fetch all elements with .plug1 class.
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('plug1');

// Add Onclick listener to all of them
for(var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) elems[i].onclick = myFunc;

// Replace Color mapping
var replaceClasses = {
  old: 'red',
  red: 'green',
  green: 'blue',
  blue: 'red'
};

function myFunc(event){
  // Element clicked
  var elem = event.target;
  // Their classes
  var classes = elem.classList;
  // Find which class he has.
  var key = Object.keys(replaceClasses).find(function(i){ return classes.contains(i); });
  // Remove this class
  classes.remove(key);
  // Add the new class
  classes.add(replaceClasses[key]);
}
```

```css
.plug1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.old { background-color: grey; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue {background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="plug1 old"></div>
<div class="plug1 old"></div>
<div class="plug1 old"></div>
<div class="plug1 old"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Steeve. This does exactly what I wanted to achieve. Not only that it is a lot less bloated. I did try classList myself after the previous suggestions I clearly couldn't get the semantics right.